# Add Multiple @Path with retrofit call

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have an api request where in the url i need to pass multiple @Path and i did so but i keep getting an error , i would like to get some help with this issue , thank you in advance

- This is sample of url

  ```
  https://api.site.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hello
  ```
- This is the retrofit setup

```
  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideRetrofitInstance(): ApiInterface {
      val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
      val interceptor = httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
      val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
              .addInterceptor(interceptor)
              .build()
      return Retrofit.Builder()
              .baseUrl("https://api.site.dev/api/v2/entries/")
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
              .client(okHttp)
              .build()
              .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
  }
```

- This is my retrofit Call

```
 Error Unable to create call adapter for class com.dic.mydictionnary.models.DictionnaryModelItem
       for method ApiInterface.getDictionnaryWord
```

*This is my apiInterfac

```
@GET("{language_code}/{word}")
   fun getDictionnaryWord(
           @Path("language_code") language : String,
           @Path("word") word : String,
   ) : DictionnaryModelItem

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Retrofit is trying to find a way of creating a `DictionnaryModelItem` for your service interface. You need to change that to this:

```
   @GET("{language_code}/{word}")
   suspend fun getDictionnaryWord(
           @Path("language_code") language : String,
           @Path("word") word : String,
   ) : Response<DictionnaryModelItem>
```

Comment: That's correct , i actually figured it out and since i used flow api , i was missing the keywod suspend , but your post actually shows the right response , thank you for your time and effort